# Proxy setting for jmeter not working properly

Tags: proxy, jmeter

I am trying to set up proxy in firefox so that I can use recoding controller from Jmeter GUI. Below is my network settings in firefox:
[image]

and also the jmeter GUI:
[image]

But when I try to load my site in firefox, I am getting the following error:

> The owner of app.example.net has configured their website improperly.
>   To protect your information from being stolen, Firefox has not
>   connected to this website.
>
> This site uses HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) to specify that
>   Firefox may only connect to it securely. As a result, it is not
>   possible to add an exception for this certificate.
>
> Learn more…
>
> Report errors like this to help Mozilla identify and block malicious
>   sites

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try running Chrome with `--ignore-certificate-errors` following [Recording stops due to HSTS](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/Recording-stops-due-to-HSTS-td5725606.html) answer in JMeter group:

> Recording stops due to HSTS
> Lily Nguyen
> 5 posts
> I had the same issue with JMeter 3.2 , using Chrome.  I got it resolved by
> invoking Chrome from command line with flag --ignore-certificate-errors
> ...This would get rid of the "Your connection is not private" error and i
> was able to record normally after installing the certificate everywhere

Or record site with [Blazemeter Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/blazemeter-the-continuous/mbopgmdnpcbohhpnfglgohlbhfongabi)

Comment: @ user7294900 I would prefer Jmeter GUI over Blazemeter

Comment: @AJ I gave an option without Blazemeter. If it doesn't work you can ask a question in JMeter or add an enhancement in bugzilla

Answer (score 0):

This is not a JMeter problem, this is a technique of protection against [MITM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) attacks called [HTTP Strict Transport Security](http://opensourceforgeeks.blogspot.com/2017/03/understanding-http-strict-transport.html)

You can try to bypass it by

1. Remove entry for your `app.example.net` from the `SiteSecurityServiceState.txt` file in the [Firefox Profile](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_Firefox) folder
2. Add the next `Integer` value at `about:config` page:

   ```
   test.currentTimeOffsetSeconds= 11491200
   ```
3. Clear your browsing history or start with the new Firefox profile

---

Be aware that there is an alternative way of recording a JMeter test: [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-new-blazeMeter-chrome-extension-v4-easily-script-jmeter-and-selenium), you will not have to worry about proxies and certificates, just execute your scenario in the browser and once done you will be able to export it as a JMeter test script.

Comment: Thank you. but I am confused with the 2nd step. Couldn't find test.currentTimeOffsetSeconds= 11491200 at about:config

Comment: You need to **ADD** this setting